# Site to site VPN with Ubuntu and StrongSwan

Tags: vpn, strongswan

I am trying to build a site-to-site IPSec VPN based on Ubuntu 20.04.1 and StrongSwan. My goal is to interconnect the two sites without using NAT on the gateways.
In my lab I have:

[image]

I could get IPSec working. From the Ubuntu on the left site I can ping 172.16.1.254 (the internal Site B gateway IP address). However, if I try to ping a machine on Site B other than 172.16.1.254 address it fails.
Following some tutorials I have:

- enabled routing at `/etc/sysctl.conf` by includding `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`; then run `sysctl -p`.
- added IPSec services to the public zone by `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=ipsec` and `firewall-cmd --reload`.
- in both sites the internal interface is bound to the `trusted` native zone and external interfaces are bound to the "public" native zone.

What am I missing? Can someone help me?

Comment: Solved. Just add the remote IP range as a source on the trusted zone.